# how to stop, start and delete a windows service in cmd with a reference to the service name

Tags: mysql, windows-service, windows-command-prompt

how to stop/start a windows service in cmd with just a fragment of the service name. Example:

```
NET STOP *part_of_name_of_service*
NET START *part_of_name_of_service*
```

For example. mysql has many versions of "the name of service".

```
MySQL57
wampmysqld
etc, etc, etc
```

The idea is to stop/start any service that contains the word "mysql". Something like that:

```
net start *MySQL*
```

But unfortunately my attempt generates error: "The service name is not valid".

**Attempts:**

1.Dump service names to a file with the following command:

```
REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services" > services.txt
findstr /i /r "mysql" services.txt
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\MySQL
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\wampmysqld64
```

but I could not complete the loop

2.With taskkill

```
call :winservices "*mysql*"

:: funcion winservices
@echo off
  goto:eof
  :winservices
  set winservices=%1
   taskkill /f /im "%winservices%" /t
  goto:eof
```

But `"*mysql*"` not works (only `"mysql*"` works)

The same happens when trying to delete the service:

```
sc delete *MySQL*
```

how I do this?

Comment: I don't know with certainty that this will work, but you might try using a WQL (Windows Query Language) statement.

Comment: A service `Name` could differ from its `DisplayName` and usually both differ from the related process name (if the service is running). Do not confuse them. Moreover, stopping a service differ from killing related process substantially. Although the `wmic.exe` utility is considered deprecated, you could parse output from `wmic path Win32_Service where "Name like '%%mysql%%' or DisplayName like '%%mysql%%'" get /Value` using the [`FOR /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution [here](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,75001,printview,page=1) (only for kill service)

```
taskkill /FI "IMAGENAME eq httpd*" /T /F
taskkill /FI "IMAGENAME eq mysql*" /T /F
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple with PowerShell:

```powershell
Stop-Service *mysql*
```

`Start-Service` and `Remove-Service` work the same, the latter is only available from PowerShell 6 onwards.